# built.sbt without .repositories file

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

My question is pretty simple. Let us consider, that I had a scala project, based on SBT. So, when I'm opening my project in IntelliJ IDEA, SBT tries to resolve dependencies during project, downloads *.jar files **.ivy2\cache** folder and compiles normally. My repositories file:

```
[repositories]
     local
     mynewproxy: http://proxy/myproject
```

The problem is I want to add some specific flags, that will be response to various ways of building - particulary describes various proxy to my repo. But replacing *repositories* file is not a convinient way, and I want to put my **repo-settings directly to build.sbt** file;

And there where my problems begin:

1. Is it possible not to use *repositories* file (just remove from .sbt folder) and put all it's information to *build.sbt*?
2. What I have to wrote in *build.sbt* instead **local** in *repositories* file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

These are called *resolvers* in sbt-parlance. The [relevant section of the sbt docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html) should be enough to get you started on configuring them.

Comment: You right, I've already use resolvers, but problem with right way of interpreting predefined value "local" of repositories file..